# Pandas columns - how to change string representation of a list to list of string?

Tags: python, pandas

I've a pandas column that has values like this `[accd, bewe, cewr, dew...]`, where `accd`, `bewe` and so on are strings but they are **without quotes**.

How do I convert that to `['accd', 'bewe', ...]` across all the rows? That is I want to apply this function to

```py
data = [['[tom,ball]', 10], ['[nick, jonas]', 15], ['[juli, roberts]', 14]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['string', 'Age'])
```

I want this df data frame to have values in string column to be 
['tom','ball'] and so on

Answer (score 0):

I think that this code do this what you want:

```
df["string"] = list(map(lambda s: s[1:-1].split(","), df["string"]))
```

`s[1:-1]` remove braces from string. then `.split(",")` split text onto parts. Map apply this operation to all elements of column and list unwrap it to assignable form.

Comment: I tried something similar, by writing a function and then applying to the column. Was thinking if there is any inbuilt function that i could use

Comment: Maybe there is, but I think that searching for it is waste of time. Or you are asking because your dataframe is big and this operation takes to long time? 

I even know that there are possibility to apply function with pandas command, but I do not remember syntax.